# Format complex json structure on grouped data with sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017, for-json

I am new to SQL json feature 
Here is the problem : I want to generate the required JSON structure from the below table data using SQL-JSON feature.

> Tabel data I have:

```
Col1    | Col2   |  Col3  | Col4
--------------------------------
School  | Room   | Jon    | Present
School  | Room   | Hanna  |Absent
School  | Room   | Teena  | NA
School  | Hall   | Length | 12
School  | Hall   | Breath | 11
School  | Hall   | Heught | 4
School  | Ground | school | xuz
School  | Ground | col    | oo
School  | Ground | else   | a
College | ClassA | teacher| 2
College | ClassA | students|20
College | ClassA | others | 1
College | ClassB | Des    | 3
College | ClassB | tv     | 0
```

> Required JSON data format

```
{
    "School":{
    
        "Room":{
          "Jon":"Present",
          "Hanna":"Absent",
          "Teena":"NA"
        },
        "Hall":{
          "Length":"12",
          "Breath":"11",
          "Heught":"4"
        },
        "Ground":{
          "school":"xuz",
          "col":"oo",
          "else":"a"
        }   
        
    },
    "College":{
        "ClassA":{
          "teacher":"2",
          "students":"20",
          "others":"1"
        },
        "ClassB":{
          "Desk":"3",
          "tv":"0"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to know how to format the data on the above given required json format with the help of `FOR JSON PATH`

Comment: Are you using postgres or sql server? Your question is tagged with both.

Comment: I'm using sql server

Comment: I don't think that you can generate this JSON output using only for `FOR JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

With Postgres, you can use `jsonb_object_agg()` to achieve this:

```
select jsonb_build_object(col1, jsonb_object_agg(col2, j1))
from (
  select col1, col2, jsonb_object_agg(col3, col4) as j1
  from t
  group by col1, col2
) t
group by col1;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=73eac44eebdff5928e243db5c9a69290)